# What does $\sum_i\sum_j$ mean? eg, $\sum_i\sum_j\frac{\rho_1^i}{i!}\frac{\rho_2^j}{j!}$

Tags: summation, notation

I have a basic question, and I haven't found a confirmation if this is correct:

If we have the notation $\sum_n n$, means the same as $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i$ so $i$ runs from its minimum value until its maximum? ($1$ would be the minimum value in this case and $n$ its maximum. I'm trying to figure out what $\sum_n$ means!

Here is the context:

I have to calculate $p(i,j) = \frac{\frac{\rho_1^i}{i!}\frac{\rho_2^j}{j!}}{N}$, where $N=\sum_i\sum_j\frac{\rho_1^i}{i!}\frac{\rho_2^j}{j!}$

Therefore my question is what is the notation $\Sigma_i\Sigma_j$

Comment: It depends upon the context. Can you provide the context?

Comment: I would understand $\Sigma_n n$ is the sum of values of $n$ where $n$ goes through a set of numbers understood from the context. For example, if you work with matrices $d\times d$, it might mean from $1$ to $d$.

Comment: please see context info added.

Comment: @user8000136: It seems to me that $i$ and $j$ are being used in multiple ways here, which is confusing. Can you provide *more* context? eg, the passage where this notation is first introduced and/or used in your source material? a link to the source itself?